# Application failed to install Android 9 (Pie)

Tags: android, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

When I try to run my project any device which has Android version is 9.0, I am getting below error. I have tried 3 different devices.

```
[ERROR] : Application failed to install
The current timeout is set to 240000 ms
You can increase this timeout by running: titanium.js config android.appInstallTimeout <timeout ms>
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

But when I run my project to device that's os is Android 7.1 I am not getting any error.

My environment specs as below

```
android.buildTools.selectVersion 9.0.0
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 7.0.9
Titanium SDK 7.5.0.GA
```

Comment: Hi, could maybe your phone be without enough space to install the app?

Comment: Thank you but there is so much place to install apk.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do the following:

```
appc ti config android.dx.maxMemory 2048m
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known Android issue. I solve it by adding the following to your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile:

`export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true"`

After adding that, I was able to install my App with MacOS in Android 9 and this should work for Linux too. For Windows check [this info](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues) for the solution to the "Gradle Sync Failed: Broken Pipe"

Also double check that "Transfer files" is enabled in Settings/Connected devices/USB in your phone. Android 9 sets the default option to "just charge" your phone.